# Continuously test where two Generalized Additive Models differ

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, generalized-additive-model

**x-axis**: time variable

**y-axis**: variable of interest

**factor**: two conditions, for example A and B

(**other variables**: to include in the model for controlling potential other influences)

In case that both conditions (A & B) have two different (non-linear) relationships, is there a way to test where on average in x the condition A and B likely differ in y? Can one do this continuously/adaptively and without creating time-bins and conducting multiple tests where one runs into the multiple testing problem?

I have created some sample code and plotted an example:

```
set.seed(358)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- sin(x) + rnorm(100)
y2 <- x^2 + rnorm(100)
dt <- data.frame(x = c(x,x), y = c(y,y2), factor = c(rep("A", times = 100), rep("B", times = 100)))
ggplot(dt, aes(x = x, y = y, group = factor, col = factor)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "gam")
```

[image: Where are there differences between conditions?]

Comment: Unfortunately the random seed is not set so we cannot reproduce this  graph.

Comment: @usεr11852 I added set.seed() and updated the plot.

Comment: Thank you! (+1). What is wrong with using `mod <- gam(data=dt, y ~ s(x) + factor)` ?

Comment: does this show where exactly the factor is different in x?

Comment: Ommpph... pasted the wrong line... `mod_2 <- gam(data=dt, y ~ s(x) + s(x, by= factor))` ?

Comment: @usεr11852 Your model needs `+ factor` and for what I think you are showing, `factor` would need to be an *ordered* factor (such that the second smooth is a smooth diff from the reference level smooth). (Either that or `m = 1` on the 2nd smooth as multiple smooths of the same variable can get unidentifiable.)

Comment: +1 Thanks Gavin. I think `m=1` is the proper thing to do.

Comment: @usεr11852 Also, thinking about this a bit more, I don't think your approach is quite what the OP wants (FWIW my first reaction was the OP wants what you suggested). Looks like they want differences on the response scale, not differences between the smooths per se. As such we'd need to include the intercept and it's uncertainty (plus the other vars at some fixed values). For that I think we'd need to do some posterior simulation and difference the fitted values for A and B...

Comment: Sure thing! I was aiming for the smooths but I appreciate your point. I did not write it as an answer anyway exactly because it was a bit unclear to me too.

Comment: @GavinSimpson @usεr11852: as written above, I wish to know at which x values the factor has different average response values y. I do not wish to split it into bins in order to conduct tests, but was wondering if there is an elegant way that avoids multiple testing problems etc. `summary(mod_2)` seems to not give an answer to this question.

Comment: @GavinSimpson a book, paper, blog post or sample code on the approach with posterior simulation would be very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: I know; as I said above, the `by` variable model yields tests against a null function not the difference between two smooths and certainly doesn't tell you where they are different. What you want to do is a little more involved than the examples I have worked up previously to answer similar questions and I'm in the middle of a hectic week at work. I know of two ways to solve this but I need some time to write up the code and example.

Comment: If you want to try yourself, `gratia::fitted_samples()` will get you the posterior simulations you want (pass it `newdata` containing your covariate at the two levels of the factor, plus something [constant] for the other two covariates, then once you have the samples, difference the fitted values at each value of x for the levels of the factor for all of the draws you generated. Then take upper and lower quantiles of your choice to get an interval on the difference for each value of x. This won't solve the multiple comparisons problem however.

Comment: You'll need something more complex for that, which involves a simultaneous interval on the differences computed as per: https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2017/10/10/difference-splines-i/ (but do not set the parametric terms to 0, and doesn't show the simultaneous interval computation).

Comment: Thank you @GavinSimpson for all the information. I will read up a bit, and try it out.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Why is the intercept per factor set to zero in the code from your blog: `X[, ! (c1 | c2)] <- 0` and `X[, !grepl('^s\\(', colnames(xp))] <- 0`
In this way I do not get the correct difference. Other than that, am I right in the assumption that I can keep the code as it is with very minor adjustments? Furthermore, I do not understand where exactly the posterior sampling occurs in your blog post, as there is no specification of the number of samples? Thank you for the kind help!

Comment: Like I said; the blog post isn't doing exactly what you want. You want the difference between expected values of the response over the range of `x` for your two groups. That post was about showing where the smooth components **only** are different. The blog post was focused on the smooth equivalent of post hoc comparisons of group means. This is why I said above that if you were following the post you would want to **not** zero out the parametric columns. There is no posterior sampling in the post; again, I did tell you this and say that it would be possible to add a simultaneous interval...

Comment: instead of using the credible interval derived from the Bayesian covariance matrix. These are separate points; i) address computing the difference you want, ii) address the desire to deal with the multiple comparisons issue. You could do i) with posterior simulation or with a modification to the by variable approach from the blog post. Dealing with ii) requires a simultaneous interval over $x$ and that will require some simulation (I have a blog posts on how to do this for smooths and for their derivatives, but again it would need modifying for your use case).

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, I overread the comment on zeroing out. Are you referring to [this](http://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2016/12/15/simultaneous-interval-revisited/) ? I will try it for my case and get back to you in the next days. Thanks again for your inputs, they are highly appreciated! And there is really no need to get back quickly to my questions in the midst of your hectic work week.